# How can I replace tab-delimited data with line breaks?

Tags: macos, google-spreadsheets

I have a lot of tab-separated data, and this means when I import that I'm getting a lot of columns (too many for Google Drive and OpenOffice).

I think what I need to do is find and replace all tabs with line breaks (could be wrong).

*EDIT - I ended up figuring this out by using a different method. Thanks everyone for your help. :)

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question, so that we all can benefit?

Answer (score 3):

On OS X you have to use `$''` to insert `\t` or `\n` and escape `\n` in the replace pattern.

```
echo $'1\t2\n3\t4' | sed $'s/\t/\\\n/g'
```

But don't linefeeds already separate lines in TSV files? You could also use TextEdit to replace the tabs with some other characters like semicolons.

Comment: Hi, need some clarification on this one. What would be the command to achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: And yes, but spreadsheets are interpreting the tabs as columns, and there are way too many columns to import and so they are getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a regular expression:

```
sed 's/\t/\n/' input.txt > output.txt
```

This will replace tabs `\t` with newlines `\n`.

Comment: Hi and thank you. Is this something I am to do in Terminal? Thanks :)

Comment: This didn't work as expected. As below, except that only the first http was changed to hnnp, all the rest of the file seems unchanged. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on root's response, you actually may need to add the /g at the end to do all the happenings.

You could also write it to the same file with an auto-backup flag.

`sed -i.orig 's/\t/\n/g' file.txt`

The ending /g will cause it to hit each happenstance instead of the first per line (if you need that).

The -i.orig writes the change to the same file after making a backup of the original (in this case file.txt.orig). That is just a matter of preference for me rather than having to then rename the original and the new one to take its place.

**Update**

I attached a screenshot to show it working for me...  You're sure the file is tab delineated?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your addition/recommendation. As above, is this something I am to perform in Terminal? Thanks will let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: Yes, this would be done in the Terminal.  And the `.orig` would be located in the same directory as whatever input file you are working with.

Comment: Hi, this didn't exactly work as planned. It replaced all of the "t" characters in the text file with "n"s, so my URLs are "hnnp" for example. I copied and pasted the code, only changing the filename.

Comment: @Drewdavid Attached a screenshot to show it working.  Perhaps the line codings aren't unix based, what was the file made using?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't clearly mention that I'm using Terminal on Mac OS X. The answer above is attempting to help but I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: Mac is a distant relative of UNIX, so it should work.  What program was this file created in?